# Injecting commonly used CDI beans in abstract parent class

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

This is more of a good practice question...

We're converting JSF managed beans to CDI beans in JSF 2.2 . While doing this, it seems in a LOT of beans, we need a few sessionscoped beans.

We initially intended to @Inject those, but another option would be to inject them into a protected variable in a parent "FacesBean" class.

1. Would this be good practice?
2. Does @Inject also work in @ManagedBean classes that were not yet converted to CDI?

Answer (score -1):

So one by one:

1) Good practice?

If you have a class hierarchy, I suggest you `@Inject` it into a *private* field in the parent and then create a getter method with minimum needed visibility (probably protected). Just stick to general good practice rules around encapsulation in Java.

2) `@ManagedBean` and `@Inject`?

As long as you use bean discovery mode `all` (use empty `beans.xml`), your classes will be automatically picked up as managed beans - including those annotated with `@ManagedBean`. And as soon as it is a bean, injection works. So yes, injection will work as long as the class can become a bean automatically (e.g. it is not `@Vetoed` or unproxyable etc.)

Comment: Thing is, declaring a private injected variable with a getter, leaves the door open for a developer to still Inject the same variable again in the subclass. Are we then injecting twice?

Comment: Well, I don't see how injecting into a protected field prevents the developer from doing exactly the same kind of mistake - but if you feel it is better, go for it, it should work. To answer your question above, you would then have two injection points, therefore yes, you would inject twice (but unless it is `@Dependent` you would in fact only inject a proxy object pointing to the *same underlying instance of the bean*).